# How we can manage async calls into Parallel.ForEach?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach

I am new at asynchronous programming and I use the following code to collect data from third-party API, and every time I am getting different responses. Am I doing the wrong approach?

```
Parallel.ForEach(products, item =>
{
    GetProductsInfo(item);
});

public async Task<Product> GetProductsInfo(Product product)
{
    var restClientProduct = new RestClient("URL");
    var restRequestProduct = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
    var proudctRequestJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new ProudctRequest()
    {
        product_code = product.product_code,

    });
    restRequestProduct.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
    restRequestProduct.AddHeader("Content-Length",
        proudctRequestJson.Count().ToString());
    restRequestProduct.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    restRequestProduct.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    restRequestProduct.AddParameter("undefined", proudctRequestJson,
        ParameterType.RequestBody);
    var responseProduct = GetResponseContentAsync(
        restClientProduct, restRequestProduct).Result;
    if (responseProduct.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        // set values form the responseProduct to the product
    }
    return product;
}

private Task<IRestResponse> GetResponseContentAsync(RestClient theClient,
    RestRequest theRequest)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<IRestResponse>();
    theClient.ExecuteAsync(theRequest, response =>
    {
        tcs.SetResult(response);
    });
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "different responses"? Also, this code isn't doing anything asynchronously. It is running in *parallel*, but not asynchronously.

Comment: You probably ought to at least pay attention to the warning that this code produces. Your async method... isn't.

Comment: @GabrielLuci   GetResponseContentAsync() this method

Comment: I'm not familiar with the RestSharp library, but even if `GetResponseContentAsync()` is running async, you're calling `.Result` on it instead of using `await`, so it is still blocking the thread and not actually running asynchronously. As @Damien_The_Unbeliever mentioned, the compiler is probably warning you about that.

Comment: Also, we still don't know what you mean by "different responses" :)

Comment: @GabrielLuci  "different responses" means some times it completes execution before completing API Calls.

Comment: Try to use Task.WaitAll or Task.WhenAll. Ex: Task.WaitAll(items.Select(i => GetProductsInfo(i))

Comment: So then you don't want it to be asynchronous? Because `Parallel.ForEach` doesn't support asynchronous operations. Or is that your issue (you want it to)?

Comment: @VolodymyrBaydalka That will work, but just a word of warning: it won't throttle the requests. If your list has 10000 records, it'll fire them all off at once, whereas `Parallel.ForEach` will send them in blocks.

Comment: @GabrielLuci So, according to if I make GetResponseContentAsync() to synchronous then it should work, right?

Comment: Maybe, but I don't see how this is running asynchronously at all, since you are calling `.Result` on it, which [will block the thread until it finishes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1.result?view=netframework-4.8#remarks). Are you using `await` somewhere in `GetProductsInfo` that you aren't showing?

Comment: @GabrielLuci let me show the flow for code execution. first Parallel.ForEach will call GetProductsInfo() which is Async inside GetProductsInfo() method i call GetResponseContentAsync() which is again aync and this GetResponseContentAsync() method will call the Third-party API to collect the data. This may help you to understand my concern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parts of your code you have shown us is not running asynchronously. You are calling `.Result` on `GetResponseContentAsync()`, which [will block the thread until it finishes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1.result?view=netframework-4.8#remarks). That means that by the time `Parallel.ForEach` completes, all the HTTP requests will have completed.

If you are using `await` somewhere in that block of code you replaced with

```
// set values form the responseProduct to the product
```

then it's possible that *the results are not being reported* before `Parallel.ForEach` finishes. That is because `Parallel.ForEach` does not support asynchronous code, so it will not wait for them to finish.

**Let's assume that `GetProductsInfo` is actually running asynchronously**

Then the problem is: `Parellel.ForEach` is not waiting for my asynchronous operations to finish. There are a couple ways to handle this.

1. Implement your own `ForEachAsync`. This has been requested, and will probably be added (to .NET Core at least) eventually. But there is actually a sample implementation in [the issue where this was requested](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/34233):

```
/// <summary>
///     Executes a foreach asynchronously.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
/// <param name="source">The source.</param>
/// <param name="dop">The degrees of parallelism.</param>
/// <param name="body">The body.</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static Task ForEachAsync<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int dop, Func<T, Task> body)
{
    return Task.WhenAll(
        from partition in System.Collections.Concurrent.Partitioner.Create(source).GetPartitions(dop)
        select Task.Run(async delegate
        {
            using (partition)
            {
                while (partition.MoveNext())
                    await body(partition.Current);
            }
        }));
}
```

That is written as an extention method, so you would use it like this:

```
await products.ForEachAsync(10, GetProductsInfo);
```

Where `10` is the number of request you would like to run at a time.

2. You can use something like:

```
Task.WaitAll(items.Select(i => GetProductsInfo(i));
```

This will run the requests asynchronously, but block the calling thread until they all finish. Alternatively, you can `await` them, so it doesn't block the calling thread:

```
await Task.WhenAll(items.Select(i => GetProductsInfo(i))
```

However, both these methods will fire off *all* of the requests at once. If you know you will only ever have a small number, then that's fine. But if you might have a very large number, you could flood the web service. Using `Parallel.ForEach`, or the implementation of `ForEachAsync` above will send them in blocks.

If you use any of these methods to await the responses, then you really should await `GetResponseContentAsync` instead of using `.Result`:

```
var responseProduct = await GetResponseContentAsync(restClientProduct, restRequestProduct);
```

Using `async`/`await` is especially important in ASP.NET, where there is a maximum number of threads it can use.